# Why is javax.validation.Valid not a Constraint and has no groups?

Tags: java, validation

I'm implementing an "easy to use" validation framework which should work similar to the Java validation framework but with some additional features like rule validation methods within the data class itself.

I wonder why javax.validation.Valid is not a constraint and has no groups?

Is this a design error or is there some reason unknown to me behind this?

Comment: Note that "rule validation methods within class itself" are supported in BVF by adding an @AssertTrue above an isSomethingSomething method.

Comment: OK That's a good approach with an adapted message. Thx